# Android: Why use PendingIntent instead of Intent to start an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I'm developing a news app, it gets the contents from the news website. I'm making a push notification service by using the new GoogleCloudMessaging technique, so i follow [Google's official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) and i noticed that they used a PendingIntent, so here are my questions:

1. What is a pending intent exactly ?
2. And how does it differ from the normal intent ?
3. Can i replace it with a normal intent and still can pass my data (extras) to my desired activity ?
4. Is there any differences in usage and implementation between the two of them ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pending intent has a special purpose-  it can be passed to other apps to allow them to call into you with the same permissions of your app that other app might not have.  `PendingIntent` should only be used when you're passing it off to another application, such as when setting a Notification (the Notification app can launch your activity via the pending intent).  There's no reason to use it internally within your app.

Comment: Yes i'm using it only for the notifications purpose.